# Mutation error with GraphQL on Apollo server

Tags: apollo

I have built an Apollo / GraphQL back-end, where the addAddress mutation:

```
mutation {
addAddress(country: "Country", city: "City", ZIP: "5444", street: "Street", housenumber: "3") 
  {
    _id
  }
}
```

Fails with the following error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "User validation failed: is_company: Path `is_company` is required., password: Path `password` is required., last_name: Path `last_name` is required., first_name: Path `first_name` is required., email: Path `email` is required.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "addAddress"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "errors": {
            "is_company": {
              "name": "ValidatorError",
              "message": "Path `is_company` is required.",
              "properties": {
                "message": "Path `is_company` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "is_company"
              },
              "kind": "required",
              "path": "is_company"
            },
            "password": {
              "name": "ValidatorError",
              "message": "Path `password` is required.",
              "properties": {
                "message": "Path `password` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "password"
              },
              "kind": "required",
              "path": "password"
            },
            "last_name": {
              "name": "ValidatorError",
              "message": "Path `last_name` is required.",
              "properties": {
                "message": "Path `last_name` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "last_name"
              },
              "kind": "required",
              "path": "last_name"
            },
            "first_name": {
              "name": "ValidatorError",
              "message": "Path `first_name` is required.",
              "properties": {
                "message": "Path `first_name` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "first_name"
              },
              "kind": "required",
              "path": "first_name"
            },
            "email": {
              "name": "ValidatorError",
              "message": "Path `email` is required.",
              "properties": {
                "message": "Path `email` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "email"
              },
              "kind": "required",
              "path": "email"
            }
          },
          "_message": "User validation failed",
          "stacktrace": [
            "ValidationError: User validation failed: is_company: Path `is_company` is required., password: Path `password` is required., last_name: Path `last_name` is required., first_name: Path `first_name` is required., email: Path `email` is required.",
            "    at model.Document.invalidate (C:\\graphql_course\\fullstack-vue-graphql-starter\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\document.js:2782:32)",
            "    at C:\\graphql_course\\fullstack-vue-graphql-starter\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\document.js:2574:17",
            "    at C:\\graphql_course\\fullstack-vue-graphql-starter\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schematype.js:1273:9",
            "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

This validation error refers to a different collection / model / schema, User, and I do not understand how this error is triggered by mutating the Address model / schema.

My whole code is accessible here : https://github.com/MrRobot555/B-Booster_back-end.git

npm i
npm run server

I would really appreciate some help since Im staring at the code for more than a day now, and I do not see my error.

Thank you

Comment: MongoDB access was restricted by IP, now it's accessible from anywhere.

Comment: Looks like an authentication error that's happening before your mutation runs. It's likely your mutation requires an authenticated user and is not getting one.

Answer (score 0):

It says the Storage path is not a accessible.

> Make sure you have declared the correct  DB_HOST Url

Also, can you check the schemas and naming conventions are used correctly. I always have this error when i change the casing of the type definitions of gql.